# Freecom NAS drive keeps going off the network

Tags: networking, hard-drive, nas

I have a Freecom network drive 500 GB which I use for backups over the network. However, it seems to go offline and has to be turned off and turned back on. Any ideas how to fix this?

The drive is: [Freecom-Network-Hard-Drive-FND-Network-Attached-Storage-NAS-500-GB](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Freecom-Network-Hard-Drive-FND-Network-Attached-Storage-NAS-500-GB-/151018854979?pt=UK_Computing_Home_Network_Storage_NAS_2&hash=item23296cda43&ssPageName=RSS:B:SHOP:GB:101)
(sorry only link i could find)

It's got the most up-to-date firmware as well.

Comment: What is your local network architecture? Does it happen when the drive is directly connected to the computer? Is there any error to be found somewhere in some error log?

Comment: @harrymc Everyone runs through a hub on a windows based network. They access the drive via network name (ie: \\drivename)

Comment: You had better give us much more info than that. This post is too vague for us to give a meaningful answer. There are my above other questions, plus info if there is any pattern to these disconnections, network architecture, router/hubs make, Event Viewer etc.

Comment: @harrymc thats the problem, I don't have any further information. No pattern, no nothing. Tips on troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: When it goes off, is it so for all computers ?

Comment: @harrymc yes. I've also turned off the 'sleep' mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which drive model is it - Silver Store?

First up, make sure you are running the latest firmware.
Second, if possible, try a different router.

Comment: It is just a Freecom Network Assisted Storage drive.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double check it is not a connection issue between the NAS and the hub or a NAS hardware failure. I currently have an external HDD which will go offline if the connection in the back is not is the absolute perfect position. If it is a hardware fault, rebooting it may temporarily fix the issue until whatever is faulty causes it to go offline.